# Mysqldump return empty file .sql

Tags: php, database

I'm try to do a dump of my db in this way:

`$output = NULL;
$command = 'mysqldump -u $dbuser -h localhost -p$password $dbname > dump.sql';
passthru($command, $output);`

I've tried in this way too:

```
$command = 'mysqldump -u $dbuser -h localhost -p$password $dbname > dump.sql';
exec($command);
```

In both ways it create an empty dump.sql

Where am I wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: If you echo/log that $command and run it from the command line, does it work for you?

Comment: https://www.emvee-solutions.com/blog/magento-create-database-backup-php-code/

Comment: @RonakRathod thank you. Is there a way to import by magento function this dump?

Comment: @RonakRathod Is there a way to import by magento function this dump?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to make use of the --single-transaction flag while using mysqldump.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u$dbuser -hlocalhost -p$password $dbname > dump.sql
```

With that said, I would suspect either a timeout (PHP or MySQL) or a out-of-memory error.

How did you executed your script?  Browser or CLI?

Comment: I've tried with your command by CLI but it sees a password character (@) as a separator and then returns an error on the command.

Answer (score 1):

I can not say exactly but if you are using single quotes, php variables wont be replaced with real values. You should use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Like $command="mysqldump -u $dbuser -h localhost -p$password $dbname > dump.sql";

Try to print command before execute to make sure that values are replaced with variables.

Let me know if that doesnt work, will give u an option to debug more accurately.

Try with below and let me know the output.

```
$command = "mysqldump -u $dbuser -h localhost -p$password $dbname > dump.sql 2>&1";
exec($command, $output);
echo '<pre>';print_r($output);exit;
```

Comment: Updated my comment to debug the command. Try it and let me know the output.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, and fixed it by adding password in my.ini file
`C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.28\my.ini`

search for `[client]`attribute and put username & password below it as

```
[client] 
user="root"
password=""
```

and then restart wamp
then you do not need to mention -p in mysqldump command

`mysqldump -u dbUserName dbName > "C:\folder1\folder2\backup.sql"`